# How to use UIWebview like UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use UIWebview like UITableView . A single webview should contains data like tableview. how can i track which data is tapped like didSelectRow in tableview

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a UITableView?

Comment: i am facing performance problem when i am loading webviews in table view cell and also Memory issues. I think when data of multiple tableview cell will be put in a single webview then performance may be improved because i didn't have to calculate height multiple times.

Comment: Are you certain you need to use a webview at all?

Comment: yes, I have to load html files so i need webview.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the table cell like html view clickable, with the link pointing to something that can be identified later in the code.

```
<a href="custom://rowclicked">your view</a>
```

In your iOS code implement the delegate to identify the above link been clicked.

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"rowclicked"]) {
         // Perform row clicked
        return NO;
      }  


   return YES;

 }
```